# JTextField area for Slick Java

Tags: java, slick2d

What i want is that i want a `JTextField` in my `Slick` Application. I know how to make one for `Java`, but not for slick. Does `Slick` have one?

I want a `TextField` that anyone can type in (like in a login form, or something).

I used this code:

```
import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.gui.TextField;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Exmaple extends BasicGameState {

TextField commandBox;

public Example(int state) {

}

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {

    commandBox = new TextField(gc, null, 20, 20, 80, 5);

}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    commandBox.render(gc, g);

}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {

//No code here

}

public int getID() {
    return 1;
    }

}
```

`commandBox` is the item that i want it to be the `TextField`. The code above doesn't work. So is there a better/similar code I can use to make a `TextField` for my game?

Comment: Per the [Slick API](http://www.slick2d.org/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/gui/TextField.html), TextField is the way to go. It looks like you're going to have to explain more fully what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: well, when i run it, i am in `stateBaseGame` 0. I click this button (with mouse input) which enters me to `stateBasedGame` 1 (the state with all the codes above in my question). but when I enter `stateBasedGame` 1, it automatically closes! tell me if you don't understand because it is a little hard to explain.

Comment: i want some anwers! `please` tell me some